# My github pages site is not applying the bootstrap jekyll theme

Tags: github-pages, jekyll-theme

My github pages site is not applying the boostrap jekyll theme, instead it looks like basic html.

the site is published here: https://toneman1984.github.io/HeatherBlogV2/

the repository is here: https://github.com/toneman1984/HeatherBlogV2

I feel like it has to do with my _config.yml file, specifically the url and base url settings and/or the settings in GitHub.

these are my config.yml settings:

```
title:              Clean Blog
email:              your-email@example.com
description:        A Blog Theme by Start Bootstrap
author:             Start Bootstrap
baseurl:            "HeathersBlogV2"
url:                "https://toneman1984.github.io/HeatherBlogV2/"

# Social Profiles
twitter_username:   SBootstrap
github_username:    StartBootstrap
facebook_username:  StartBootstrap
instagram_username:  
linkedin_username:

# Add your google-analytics ID here to activate google analytics
google_analytics:   UA-XXXXXXXXX-X # out your google-analytics code

# Build settings
markdown:           kramdown
paginate:           5
paginate_path:      "/posts/page:num/"
plugins:
  - jekyll-feed
  - jekyll-paginate
  - jekyll-sitemap ## Uncomment this line to silently generate a sitemaps.org compliant sitemap for your Jekyll site

theme: jekyll-theme-clean-blog
```

Comment: see your sight that is completely same as the theme.

Comment: Hey man, have you got it at the end? Thanks